# BottomSheet + ViewPager2 drag to hide not works

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet, android-viewpager2

I got troubles and I think it is `CoordinatorLayout`'s fault but not sure. I'm using `ViewPager2` inside a `ConstraintLayout` and I use the `CoordinatorLayout` like `BottomSheet`. But when I drag to hide it not works good. I replaced the `ViewPager2` by `ViewPager` and it works well. I hope you can help me.

This is my XML file:

```
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="60dp" >

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:background="#0000FF"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by disabling the nested scrolling of the `ViewPager2` `RecyclerView`; but since the `RecyclerView` can't be directly accessed through the `ViewPager2` library. Then it can't be achieved in layout.

So, instead we can get that `RecyclerView` using java reflection as follows:

Java:

```
public static RecyclerView getRecyclerView(ViewPager2 viewPager) {
    try {
        Field field = ViewPager2.class.getDeclaredField("mRecyclerView");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return (RecyclerView) field.get(viewPager);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Kotlin:

```
fun ViewPager2.getRecyclerView(): RecyclerView? {
    try {
        val field = ViewPager2::class.java.getDeclaredField("mRecyclerView")
        field.isAccessible = true
        return field.get(this) as RecyclerView
    } catch (e: NoSuchFieldException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    } catch (e: IllegalAccessException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}
```

Then disable the nested scrolling:

Java:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = getRecyclerView(viewPager);
if (recyclerView != null) {
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER); // Optional
}
```

Kotlin:

```
val recyclerView = viewPager.getRecyclerView()
recyclerView?.isNestedScrollingEnabled = false
recyclerView?.overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER // Optional
```

This works with me without setting the `OverScrollMode`, so, if it doesn't work with you can disable the `OverScrollMode` like above.